# server и client code в разных проектах, но в одном решении

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net

Хочется сделать так чтобы в одном решении было два проекта, один asp.net webapi, а другой просто html страница с набором js скриптов и чтобы при нажатии f5 все это запускалось вместе, а в браузере открывалась html страница.Как это реализовать в visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В Visual Studio вызвать контекстное меню у Solution, выбрать `Add | Existing Web Site...` Выбрать каталог с файлами сайта.
2. Вызвать контекстное меню у Solution, выбрать `Properties`. В появившемся диалоге выбрать `Common Properties | Startup Project`. Выбрать `Multiple startup projects`. Для WebApi выбрать `Action` `Start`, для сайта - `Start without debugging`.
3. Чтобы в браузере не открывалась страница для WebApi приложения, нужно вызвать контекстное меню у проекта WebApi. Выбрать `Properties`. Вкладка `Web`. `Start Action` -> `Don't open a page. Wait from a request an external application`.